# Zoom inside of a container with HSlider component

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

Is there any way to use a `HSlider` to zoom (with percentage value) inside of a component?

I actually have a container:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="suppCont" x="238" y="10" width="710" height="514"
                   backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" borderAlpha="0.4" cornerRadius="5"></s:BorderContainer>
```

And i would like to be able to use this `HSlider` to zoom inside of the `BorderContainer`:

```
<s:HSlider x="597" y="491" maximum="500" minimum="0" stepSize="50" value="100"/>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zoom effect or just change the scale of BorderComponent, like this:

```
<s:HSlider id="slider" minimum="0" maximum="100" thumbDrag="slider_thumbDragHandler(event)" />
<s:BorderContainer id="borderComponent">
    //some content
    ....
    ....
</s:BorderContainer>
```

And handlere like this:

```
protected function slider_thumbDragHandler(event:TrackBaseEvent):void
{
    trace(slider.value);

    borderComponent.scaleX = (1 + slider.value/100);
    borderComponent.scaleY = (1 + slider.value/100);
}
```